# Problem with bootstrap carousel and Navbar on the same page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying fitting bootstrap carousel (90% of total height on top) and bootstrap Navbar (10% of total height on the bottom) on the same page. It actually works, but when I resize the page vertically, carousel doesn't resize, and Navbar start moving out of the 100vh. How can I resize carousel section for keeping the Navbar to a min-height of 10%?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montez&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap');

.selector-for-some-widget {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 9vw;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 5vw;
}

p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective: 10px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90%;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.background {
  transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  filter: brightness(50%);
}

.title {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montez', cursive;
}

section {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

nav {
  min-height: 10%;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Montez', cursive;
  font-size: 1.85rem;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.fill {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Style CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <title>Ariano Francesco Photography</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide background" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active vh-100">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/cover_bg_1.jpg');"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item vh-100">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/cover_bg_1.jpg');"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item vh-100">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/cover_bg_1.jpg');"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Ariano Francesco</h1>
        <h2>Photography</h2>
      </div>
    </header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white sticky-top shadow-sm">
      <div class="container-fluid px-5">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AFR</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar"
          aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar"
          aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
          <div class="offcanvas-header justify-content-end">
            <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="offcanvas-body d-flex text-center align-items-center">
            <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <section>
      <div class="container p-5">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
            <img src=""
              class="w-100 rounded mb-4" alt="" />

            <img src="" class="w-100 rounded mb-4"
              alt="" />
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src=""
              alt="" />

            <img src=""
              class="w-100 rounded mb-4" alt="" />
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src=""
              class="w-100 rounded mb-4" alt="" />

            <img src="" class="w-100 rounded mb-4"
              alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Script.js -->
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not carousel not resizing. Your carousel and nav will both resize to fit the screen by 9:1.
But in order to fully show your nav bar on the screen with small height, the contents inside the nav bar should shrink along the the nav bar's height.